# postgresql select boolean states in timeseries

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a particular problem were i'm stuck and seeking some help...

I have a timeseries type of tables where I store switch toggle value when a device is set on or off. State 0 event mean the device is turned off, State 1 event mean the device is turned on.

```
time                | state
------------------------------
2018-06-10 12:20:00 | 0
2018-06-10 12:30:00 | 1
2018-06-10 13:10:00 | 0
2018-06-10 16:50:00 | 1
2018-06-10 20:23:00 | 0
2018-06-10 21:10:00 | 1
2018-06-10 21:30:00 | 0
```

I need to make a report of usage by hours, mean generating an output like:

```
date                | in_use
-------------------------------
2018-06-10 12:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 13:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 14:00:00 | 0
2018-06-10 15:00:00 | 0
2018-06-10 16:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 17:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 18:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 19:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 20:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 21:00:00 | 1
2018-06-10 22:00:00 | 0
```

I'm not sure how to proceed to get this type of result with postgres.
What do you think ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the logic.  Why is 13:00 a `0`, but the `1` repeat for later hours?

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake. 13:00 should read 1.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to take the state for an hour where the log time is the maximum time less than the hour (that follows, your example is wrong for 16:00 (should be the state of 13:10) and 21:00 (should be the state of 20:23)):

Use `generate_series()` to get all hours. For the start use `date_trunc()` on the minimum time and for the end also use `date_trunc()` but on the maximum time and also add an hour.

To get the state with the maximum time less than the hour use a correlated subquery. Because for the first hour there may be no such state the subquery may return null. For that case use `coalesce()` to replace the null value by the negation of the first value in the log (ordered by time).

```
SELECT "gs"."date",
       coalesce((SELECT "t2"."state"
                        FROM "elbat" "t2"
                        WHERE "t2"."time" < "gs"."date"
                        ORDER BY "t2"."time" DESC
                        LIMIT 1),
                (SELECT NOT "t3"."state"
                        FROM "elbat" "t3"
                        ORDER BY "t3"."time" ASC
                        LIMIT 1)) "in_use"
       FROM (SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('hour', min("t1"."time")),
                                    date_trunc('hour', max("t1"."time"))
                                    + INTERVAL '1 HOUR',
                                    '1 HOUR') "date"
                    FROM "elbat" "t1") "gs";
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=70ea152bc3f3b6a79ff8f529261a064d)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I just like to mention that I don't whant the state a the start of the hour, but during the our. Mean that is the device was off at 21:00 but is switched on during the hour, we should report that the device was on durning the hour.